# How to turn this function into a future?

Tags: flutter, dart

I think I'll get chewed out for asking this question but I've been searching for a while and would like a little help!

I have this piece of code. How would I abandon having to use the callback and just return a future.

```dart
void getProducts({required Function() callback}) {
    List<Product> results = [];
    _firestore
        .collection('available_products')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
        print(doc);
        results.add(Product(
            name: doc['name'],
            category: doc['category'],
            description: doc['description'],
            price: doc['price']));
      }
      allProducts = results; 
      callback();
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
      print(error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Do you want to return a list of products?

Comment: Yes exactly, just  having trouble formatting it as a future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `void` use the data type you want to return, `List<Product>`.
The rest of the code is just converting `.then` to `async await` syntax. You can still use the `.then` syntax though. This is just easier to understand IMO.

Here's the code snippet.

```dart
Future<List<Product>> getProducts() async {
  List<Product> results = [];

  try {
    final querySnapshot =
        await _firestore.collection('available_products').get();

    for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
      print(doc);
      results.add(Product(
            name: doc['name'],
            category: doc['category'],
            description: doc['description'],
            price: doc['price']
          ));
    }

      allProducts = results;
  } catch (error) {
    print(error);
  }

  return results;
}
```

Further, you can return any other data types in place of `List<Product>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
Future<void> getProducts({required Function() callback}) async{
    List<Product> results = [];
    await _firestore
        .collection('available_products')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
        print(doc);
        results.add(Product(
            name: doc['name'],
            category: doc['category'],
            description: doc['description'],
            price: doc['price']));
      }
      allProducts = results; 
      callback();
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
      print(error);
    });
  }
```